# How to except TimeOutError during WMS query?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, timeout, wms, cartopy

I need your advice. 
I am establishing a connection with the WMS (Web Map Service). If the connection has been established, WMS is added to be drawn in the matplot window. In most cases, the image from WMS is displayed correctly. However, there are cases when the image from the WMS is loaded too long, which causes errors (which I attached below). This is TimeOut Error usually.

I would like to bring my code to a form in which at the moment when TimeOut is exceeded the image from WMS stops loading. I want to avoid image requesting again.

For this purpose I would like except TimeError. Unfortunately, I cannot. Of course, I tried the

> except:

method (without specifying errors), but it does not work. The code below does not work either.

```
try:
    resp = requests.get('http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer')
    odpowiedz_wms = resp.status_code except:
    resp.status_code = 0 if resp.status_code == 200:
    wms = ax.add_wms(wms='http://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/img/guest/ORTO/MapServer/WMSServer', layers=['Raster'])
    try:
        plt.draw()
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException,socket.timeout,timeout, exceptions.ConnectionError,ReadTimeout, TimeoutError, exceptions.Timeout,exceptions.ReadTimeoutError,ReadTimeoutError,exceptions.ConnectTimeout, exceptions.ReadTimeout, requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError, socket.timeout) as e:
        wms.remove()
        plt.draw()
```

> > Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): (...)
> >
> > File "C:\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
> >         return self._sock.recv_into(b) socket.timeout: timed out
> >
> > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> >
> > Traceback (most recent call last):   (...)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 306,
> >     in _raise_timeout
> >         raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value) urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError:
> >     HTTPConnectionPool(host='mapy.geoportal.gov.pl', port=80): Read timed
> >     out. (read timeout=30)
> >
> > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> >
> > Traceback (most recent call last):  (...) r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 526, in send
> >         raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
> >     HTTPConnectionPool(host='mapy.geoportal.gov.pl', port=80): Read timed
> >     out. (read timeout=30)

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown in a piece of code

- The stack will unwind until it reaches an exception handler (try - except block)
- If another exception is raised during handling of the exception (in the except block code). Then the stack will unwind further to the next exception handler capable of catching the exception. The exception that now needs to be handled is not the original exception. It is now the last exception raised
- If the call stack unwinds to the point that there are no exception handlers further up the call stack then the process will terminate and the stack trace will be dumped onto your screen showing all of the errors
- Many libraries contain loggers, which will print out the stack trace during handling of an exception. In these cases you will still get the stack trace dumped to your screen. But the exception will not necessarily terminate the process. It may be handled.
- It's good practice to implement logging in your exception handlers so that you know which exceptions are occuring and so that you can debug if something goes wrong
- In this case the current exception that your code would have to  handle is no the first exception thrown. It is the ReadTimeout that would need to be handled. Although, using except with no arguments is a surefire way to catch anything that comes up. **This method of exception handling must be used with caution and only as a last resort. It will often catch exceptions that are genuine bugs that you never intended to catch. Always try to specify the type of exception you actually intend on catching**

## Example

```
try:
    try:
        1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # Catches the ZeroDivisionError
        raise IndexError
except IndexError:
    # Catches the IndexError - Doesn't need to catch the ZeroDivisionError
    raise NameError # raises unhandled exception. Process terminated and entire stack trace will be printed
```

## Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "pyex.py", line 14, in <module>
     1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyex.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise IndexError
IndexError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyex.py", line 21, in <module>
    raise NameError # raises unhandled exception. Entire stack trace 
will be printed out
NameError
```

Comment: I've tried run the code with just except. Exception handling still does not work. Program doesn't terminate and program try to plot WMS image despite of errors.